# jQuery code is working on JSFiddle, but not in my web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

I am running into a strange issue using jQuery. I have a set of buttons on the page that, when long-clicked, are meant to popup an input box at the location of the button. **[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhDBrown/8V6pn/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="popupView" id="recoveryView">
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery0" id="recovery0">00:30</button>
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery6" id="recovery6">00:35</button>
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery1" id="recovery1">02:00</button>
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery7" id="recovery7">03:00</button>
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery2" id="recovery2">04:00</button>
    <button class="intervalBtn" type="button" name="recovery8" id="recovery8">05:00</button>
</div>
<input id="edit_interval" type="text" />
```

**CSS**

```
.popupView {
    background: #999999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #333333;
    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
}
.intervalBtn {
    color: blue;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    width: 41%;
    height: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    font: 12pt sans-serif;
}
.recoveryBtn {
    color: blue;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    width: 88%;
    height: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    font: 12pt sans-serif;
}
.intervalBtn.selected, .recoveryBtn.selected {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    background: blue;
}
body {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
body > div {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#edit_interval {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".intervalBtn").click(function () {
    $(".intervalBtn").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearTimeout(pressTimer);
    return false;
}).mousedown(function () {
    // Set timeout
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("interval button long click");

        $("#edit_interval").css("display", "block").css("left", $(this).position().left).css("top", $(this).position().top);
    }, 1000)
    return false;
});
```

If run in the fiddle, the only problem is the location of the box (am I getting the left and top positions incorrectly?), however when I test on the actual web app (in Safari), I get the following error after the long click log, an no input box appears:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 't in e')

at

> jQuery.min.js: 5

So this is a two-part question (with emphasis on part 1):

1. **Why am I getting this error (is it a bug?), and how can I fix it?**
2. **How can I set the input box to the correct location?**

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments, I swapped out `jquery.min.js` for `jquery.js`, and have an error that is easier to debug:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 'name in style')

at line 6643. Here is the code from `jQuery.js`:

```
// return a css property mapped to a potentially vendor prefixed property
function vendorPropName( style, name ) {

    // shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed
    if ( name in style ) {   //<---This is the line that causes the error
        return name;
    }

    // check for vendor prefixed names
    var capName = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1),
        origName = name,
        i = cssPrefixes.length;

    while ( i-- ) {
        name = cssPrefixes[ i ] + capName;
        if ( name in style ) {
            return name;
        }
    }

    return origName;
}
```

Does this mean that jQuery can't find the CSS properties *left* and *top*?

Comment: (Just a shot at this): can you try: `(function ($) {
   //your jQuery code here
}(jQuery));` It could be an issue with the jQuery `noconflict` mode

Comment: @karthikr, where do I add that? I tried placing it before my jQuery code, but it did not work.

Comment: do this in place of `$(document.ready()`

Comment: This did not work. Thanks for trying!

Comment: one more thing i can recommend is, you can replace the min with the normal js and see if you can understand what is going on. Sorry for not being helpful

Comment: @karthikr, nice tip! I did that and am able to debug a little. I will update my post with the new details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 2 of your question, your `this` is not the `this` you expect since it is scoped inside the `window.setTimeout()` function. You'll need to get a reference to `this` (or just the position of the clicked element) outside the scope of `setTimeout()`. The relevant code is below. I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8V6pn/2/). Note that the [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) function doesn't take into account margins or padding.

```
var pos = $(this).position();

// Set timeout
pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    console.log("interval button long click");

    $("#edit_interval").css({"left": pos.left + 'px', "top": pos.top + 'px'}).show();
},1000)
return false;
```

Comment: This fixed both issues! It must have been the bad reference to `this`. This had me really stuck - thanks a bunch (+1 & accept)!